# Translating RCON to Java

Tags: java, c, sockets, remote-access

I'm working on implementing a RCON for Minecraft, which uses the Valve rcon protocol, and I've gotten my hands on the C source and tried to implement it into Java, this is what I've done so far:

Creating the packet:
http://pastebin.com/9AeiSQPD

Recieve the packet: http://pastebin.com/n6V1KnPa

Send the packet: http://pastebin.com/rixhD15p

I'm sending the AUTH packet to the server and trying to receive a response, but the return value is null, also trying to send a command throws:

> Software caused connection abort: socket write error

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why not paste those blocks of code into the question?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two wrong things in your code.

1) First as you can see [here](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_RCON_Protocol#Basic_Packet_Structure) the packet structure use **4 bytes** blocks (32bits) of **little-endian** integer. The means **reverse blocks** (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)).

2) Second you didnt use null block (**empty String** or null character) at end of packet.

Solution:

1) Use: (ByteBuffer and ByteOrder are from native java.nio java7)

```
writer.write(ByteBuffer.allocate(4).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)
    .putInt(p.size).array());
writer.write(ByteBuffer.allocate(4).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)
    .putInt(p.id).array());
writer.write(ByteBuffer.allocate(4).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)
    .putInt(p.cmd).array());
```

Instead of:

```
writer.writeInt(p.size);
writer.writeInt(p.id);
writer.writeInt(p.cmd);
```

and:

```
ByteBuffer.wrap(<4_BLOCKS_BYTES>)
    .order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt();
```

instead of:

```
reader.readInt();
```

where `<4_BLOCKS_BYTES>` is a bytes array of size 4, read from the reader.

And if I can give you an advice, it can be easier (I think) to use a global buffer to send.
I mean a buffer containing size, id, type, data and empty block as bytes. And same thing when you read response: use a buffer to read while the `DataInputStream` is `available()` and then parse it.

Good luck!

Java Doc links:
java.nio: docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/package-frame.html
DataInputStream.available(): docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html#available()

Comment: All I had to do was add the null block and it worked.